# RectangleSelector Disappears on Zoom

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

When I run [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/rectangle_selector.html) example and create a rectangular selection if I zoom or move the plot window around the selection disappears until I deselect the move or zoom tool and click on the plot window again.

I am using `%matplotlib tkinter` in an IPython notebook.

I've attempted hooking into the limit changes that occur when the window is zoomed and setting the rectangular selection to visible:

```
def persist_rect(newlims):
    rs = toggle_selector.RS
    print(rs.visible)
    rs.set_visible(True)
    rs.update()

current_ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', persist_rect)
current_ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', persist_rect)
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't even appear that `toggle_selector.RS.visible` is ever set to false.

I've also been looking at the [source for RectangleSelector](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L1924), but I haven't seen anything enlightening there.

I've also discovered that I have this issue when I modify the extent of the selected region using `RectangleSelector.extents = new_extents`. When `.extents` is modified, for example with a slider widget, the selected region disappears until I click on the plot again.

All of these problems problems go away if the `RectangleSelector` is initialized with `useblit=False` as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggests, but, as they say, it's not a very performant solution.

Comment: Have you check this questions answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517484/persistent-rectangle-selector?

Comment: @JafferWilson: Thanks for pointing to that question. Unfortunately the answer is not working. When being used as it is, the Rectangle will instantly disappear. If being used with `interactive=True`, the same issue as in the above question remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a callback for `draw_event`s:

```
def mycallback(event):
    if RS.active:
        RS.update()
plt.connect('draw_event', mycallback)
```

makes the `RectangleSelector` persist after zooming or panning, and is compatible with `useblit=True`.

---

For example, using the [code from the docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/rectangle_selector.html) as a base:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets
import threading
import datetime as DT

def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, erelease.button))

def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed: {}'.format(event.key))
    if event.key in ['D', 'd'] and RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        RS.set_active(False)
        RS.set_visible(False)
        RS.update()
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        RS.set_active(True)
        RS.set_visible(True)
        RS.update()

def mycallback(event):
    if RS.active:
        # print('mycallback')
        RS.update()

# def persist_rect(newlims):
#     print('persist_rect')
#     RS.set_visible(True)
#     RS.update()

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
# figtype = type(fig)
# figtype._draw = figtype.draw
# def mydraw(self, renderer):
#     print('figure.draw')
#     self._draw(renderer)
# figtype.draw = mydraw

N = 100000               
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N) 

RS = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                       button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                       spancoords='pixels',
                       interactive=True)

plt.plot(x, +np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='b', alpha=.7) 
plt.plot(x, +np.cos(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='r', alpha=.5)
plt.plot(x, -np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='g', alpha=.3)

plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.connect('draw_event', mycallback)
# ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', persist_rect)
# ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', persist_rect)

plt.show()
```

---

*Why does `mycallback` work but `persist_rect` doesn't?*

If you uncomment the commented-out statements above, you'll get some printed output which will look something as this:

```
figure.draw
mycallback
figure.draw
mycallback
(4.09, -0.53) --> (8.15, 0.38)
 The button you used were: 1 1
persist_rect
persist_rect
figure.draw
mycallback
 Key pressed: q
```

Notice that `persist_rect` gets called before `figure.draw`, while `mycallback` is called afterwards. `figure.draw` does not draw the `RectangleSelection`, but it does draw the `Rectangle` used for the background. So `figure.draw` obscures `RectangleSelection`. 
Thus `persist_rect` momentarily displays `RectangleSelection`, but it fails to persist.
`mycallback` works because it is called after `figure.draw`.

Comment: Indeed! Is there any good explanation for that? In principle this is very close to what OP tried with the callback on the limits change (and which doesn't work). Also it seems unintuitive to call `.update`, which would actually draw the rectangle, *on a callback* of a draw event. Feels a bit like the snake bites its own tail, but it's obviously working.

Comment: I think it boils down to the order in which the callbacks are called relative to `figure.draw`. `persist_rect` gets called before `figure.draw`, while `mycallback` gets called afterwards. Since `figure.draw` draws on top of the `RectangleSelector`, `persist_rect` fail to keep the `RectangleSelector` persistently visible. I've added some monkey-patching code above to show when `figure.draw` gets called.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, the rectangle selector should stay visible throughout the process of panning or zooming. This could be achieved by not using blitting,

```
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, ...,  useblit=False, ...)
```

A side effect of this is that the plotting may become slow depending on the complexity of the plot, as without blitting, the complete plot is continuously redrawn while using the rectangle selector.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately this isn't an optimal solution for me. I wanted to use the rectangle selector to select regions on waterfall plots drawn with `imshow`. The smallest of these waterfall arrays are ~18MB and the largest are around ~220MB. `RectangleSelector` works wonderfully with blitting except for this redrawing problem. Is there any way I can manually force it to redraw after a zoom/move?

Comment: This works wonderfully for simple plots. I'll happily +1 when I have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code for [RectangularSelector](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L1924) the release method  ([line 2119](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a455f1cdfd7b9efd8a86c5857b437192bb41f4ff/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L2119)) 
 handles the visibility of the selector

```
def _release(self, event):   
"""on button release event"""
    if not self.interactive:
        self.to_draw.set_visible(False)
```

Subclass RectangleSelector to modify the release method

```
class visibleRectangleSelector(RectangleSelector):
    def release(self, event):
        super(visibleRectangleSelector, self).release(event)
        self.to_draw.set_visible(True)
        self.canvas.draw()   ##updates canvas for new selection
```

Sample Code using [doc](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/rectangle_selector.html) example

```
from __future__ import print_function
"""
Do a mouseclick somewhere, move the mouse to some destination, release
the button.  This class gives click- and release-events and also draws
a line or a box from the click-point to the actual mouseposition
(within the same axes) until the button is released.  Within the
method 'self.ignore()' it is checked whether the button from eventpress
and eventrelease are the same.

"""
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class visibleRectangleSelector(RectangleSelector):
    def release(self, event):
        super(visibleRectangleSelector, self).release(event)
        self.to_draw.set_visible(True)
        self.canvas.draw() 


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button,
                                                erelease.button))


def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)


fig, current_ax = plt.subplots()  # make a new plotting range
N = 100000  # If N is large one can see
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N)  # improvement by use blitting!

plt.plot(x, +np.sin(.2 * np.pi * x), lw=3.5, c='b', alpha=.7)  # plot something
plt.plot(x, +np.cos(.2 * np.pi * x), lw=3.5, c='r', alpha=.5)
plt.plot(x, -np.sin(.2 * np.pi * x), lw=3.5, c='g', alpha=.3)

print("\n      click  -->  release")

# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(
    current_ax,
    line_select_callback,
    drawtype='box',
    useblit=False,
    button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
    minspanx=5,
    minspany=5,
    spancoords='pixels',
    interactive=True)
plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue. However, it seems that this solution is only working because you used `blit=False` as in  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45531329/4124317). When using `blit=False`, no subclassing is needed at all. When trying this solution with `blit=True`, the RectangleSelector still disappears. So it does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Seen from 
@JafferWilson's comment above, this answer is a **plagiate** of the answer to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517484/persistent-rectangle-selector).